# Set select "height" in CSS unless "size" is greater than 1

Tags: html, css

I want to update my CSS page to set a standard height for all select boxes unless the box is a multi-select box and the size isn't any greater than 1.

I have the first part of this figured out:

```
select{
    height:24px;
}
select[multiple]{
    height:auto;
}
```

This works well, except for select boxes like this:

```
<select size="10">
```

Is there a way to make an exception for these types of select boxes just using CSS like I did for the mutiple-select boxes? I could accomplish this by updating all these select boxes with a new class, but would rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: `select[multiple], select[size] {height: auto;}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFe73/)

For some reason the CSS selector only works on my browser with quotes around the `5`

### CSS

```
select:not([multiple]):not([size]) {
    height: 24px;
}
select[size='10'], select[multiple] {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following CSS selectors, in that order:

```
select[multiple], select[size] {
    height: auto;
}
select, select[size="1"] {
    height: 24px;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/dC8Xs/)